# UITableViewCell textLabel color not changing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got a UITableView and as the cellForRowAtIndexPath method I am changing some attributes of the cell (font, size, etc.)  Now all of the assignments listed below work just fine except changing the color of the textLabel.  I can't figure out why only that specific color attribute won't change.  I've looked about everywhere I can think of to figure out why it isn't working and I'm stuck.  Any ideas?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *kLocationAttributeCellID = @"bAttributeCellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kLocationAttributeCellID];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:kLocationAttributeCellID] autorelease];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
        cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:18.0];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; // this never takes effect...
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test Label";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Test Details";
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because of this:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

If you don't want your cells to be selectable, try using this instead:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: Oh wow...what the crap.  I wonder why that has an effect on the color.  I've been trying to solve this for like 3 days now. Thanks!!!

Comment: Year 2019 and I still have the same problem. Removing userInteractionEnabled = false fixed the problem :(