# Swift: Can't edit properties of custom table cell programmatically

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview, uibackgroundcolor

I am trying to change the colour of a view inside a custom table cell and I have an outlet to it, which works. I can change other properties of this view, like `.isHidden` but `.backgroundColor` doesn't seem to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

`UIColor`(named: "Green") works in other parts of the app, but I can't change the colour of the text with it either. Am I assigning the wrong type of color? Are the values from the storyboard just overwriting this? If so, how could I stop that from happening? Changing it to `= .red` doesn't work either.

Here's the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChapterCell") as! ChapterCell
    smallLabel(cell.chapterLabel, 18)
    cell.keepSubviewBackground = true

    if chapters[indexPath.row].completed == true {
        cell.chapterNumber.isHidden = true
        cell.chapterTick.isHidden = false
        cell.chapterLabel?.text = chapters[indexPath.row].generateTitle()
        cell.chapterLabel?.textColor = UIColor(named: "Green")
        cell.chapterNumberContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Green")
    } else {
        cell.chapterLabel?.text = chapters[indexPath.row].generateTitle()
        cell.chapterNumber?.text = "#\(indexPath.row + 1)"
        cell.chapterTick.isHidden = true
        cell.chapterNumber.isHidden = false
        cell.chapterNumberContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "Eggshell")
    }

    if chapters[indexPath.row].locked == true {
        cell.chapterLabel?.alpha = 0.3
        cell.chapterNumberContainer?.alpha = 0.3
    } else {
        cell.chapterLabel?.alpha = 1
        cell.chapterNumberContainer?.alpha = 1
    }

    let cellBGView = UIView()
    cellBGView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.00, green: 1.00, blue: 1.00, alpha: 0.1)
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellBGView

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hm, thanks @GaloTorresSevilla , the view is created in the storyboard and it does render correctly. The problem is the colour doesn't change. I have an outlet from the view so I thought this will change its background colour. I can use the outlet to hide it with .isHidden for example. https://www.dropbox.com/s/8z95rb2ozdgmfnt/Screenshot%202019-03-23%20at%2016.28.19.png?dl=0 

Would there be any other details about the project that would help?

Comment: Don't instantiate a view in the table's data source. The data source, when working with reusable cells, should be as lightweight as possible. All it should do is inject the cell with data. Do all of the heavy lifting elsewhere. In the case of a selected background, code that in the cell itself.

Comment: Consider making two cells, each styled in their own ways and dequeue the desired cell in the data source based on the data. Try not to get into the business of styling cells in the data source, particularly toggling views in the cell's hierarchy, auto layout will hate you, your scrolling performance could take a noticeable hit, and things could definitely get buggy.

Comment: It looks like that's what I'll have to do, thank you.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355709/font-color-for-uilabel-not-changing

Answer (score 1):

Check this,It can be an issue here.
[UITableViewCell textLabel color not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559254/uitableviewcell-textlabel-color-not-changing)
Notes:Can't comment for less reputation.That's why posted it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't seem to make any difference. I tried adding isUserInteractionEnabled = false (or true) to both the cell and the view, and the colour still won't change. Every other property works fine, just not the colour for some reason. Or did I misinterpret the answer you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all the suggestions, I ended up going with the solution that bsod suggested and I'd like to provide more details for anyone who needs this in the future. Rob's solution didn't work for me.

1. Duplicate the first custom cell inside the tableview and stylise it however you want.

[image]

2. Create a second class and assign it to the second cell, as well as a new identifier. You can also create any outlets you need in this second class and they can have the same name.

[image]
[image]

3. In the cellForRowAt indexPath method, I've used an if statement to dequeue the custom cells based on whether a chapter is completed or not and then style them accordingly. This repeats some code but the cell has to be type cast to work (if anyone can think of a way to do this better, I'm open to alternatives).

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   ```
   if chapters[indexPath.row].completed == false {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RegularCell") as! RegularCell

       cell.chapterLabel?.text = chapters[indexPath.row].generateTitle()
       cell.chapterNumber?.text = "#\(indexPath.row + 1)"

       if chapters[indexPath.row].locked == true {
           cell.chapterLabel?.alpha = 0.3
           cell.chapterNumberContainer?.alpha = 0.3
       } else {
           cell.chapterLabel?.alpha = 1
           cell.chapterNumberContainer?.alpha = 1
       }

       let cellBGView = UIView()
       cellBGView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.00, green: 1.00, blue: 1.00, alpha: 0.1)
       cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellBGView
       smallLabel(cell.chapterLabel, 18)
       cell.keepSubviewBackground = true

       return cell
   } else {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CompletedCell") as! CompletedCell

       cell.chapterLabel?.text = chapters[indexPath.row].generateTitle()

       let cellBGView = UIView()
       cellBGView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.00, green: 1.00, blue: 1.00, alpha: 0.1)
       cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellBGView
       smallLabel(cell.chapterLabel, 18)
       cell.keepSubviewBackground = true

       return cell
   }
   ```